# How to receive UTF-8 encoded messages via TIdIMAP4?

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

I am trying to receive emails using Indy's `TIdIMAP4` component.

Here's some example code for how I retrieve the messages:

```
procedure TEmailForm.GetMessage(ID: string);
var
  IMAP: TIdIMAP4;
  Msg: TIdMessage;
begin
  IMAP := TIdIMAP4.Create(Self);
  IMAP.Host := 'mailserver';
  IMAP.Username := 'username';
  IMAP.Password := 'password';
  IMAP.Connect(True);
  IMAP.SelectMailBox('INBOX');
  Msg := TIdMessage.Create(Self);
  IMAP.UIDRetrieve(ID, Msg);
  Subject.Caption := Msg.Subject;
  if (Msg.MessageParts.Count = 0) then
    MsgBody.Text := Msg.Body.Text
  else if (Msg.MessageParts[0] is TIdText) then
    MsgBody.Text := TIdText(Msg.MessageParts[0]).Body.Text;
  IMAP.Disconnect();
  IMAP.Free;
end;
```

Where `Subject` is a `TLabel` and `MsgBody` a `TMemo`.

In case the email is a multi-part message like messages sent via Gmail, the body returned by `TIdText(Msg.MessageParts[0]).Body.Text` is correctly encoded and special characters like German umlauts are displayed correctly.

Though in case the email is a single-part message like messages sent via GMX, all special characters within the message body returned by `Msg.Body.Text` are replaced by question marks (`?`).

Retrieving the message body instead via

```
IMAP.UIDRetrieveText(ID, MsgText);
```

results in Mojibake like `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃÃ±Â²`.

The expected characters are `äöüßñ²`.

FWIW fetching the message body via Telnet I get this:

```
a06 UID FETCH 100 (BODY)
* 244 FETCH (BODY ("text" "html" ("charset" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7BIT" 206 2) UID 1
00)
a06 OK FETCH completed.
a07 UID FETCH 100 BODY[TEXT]
* 244 FETCH (BODY[TEXT] {206}
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>
<div style="font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12.0px;"><div>├ñ├Â├╝├ƒ
</div></div></body></html>
 UID 100 FLAGS (\Seen))
a07 OK FETCH completed.
```

So what's the correct way to retrieve the message body of this kind of UTF-8 encoded single-part emails? I.e. how to decode them correctly?

Comment: You need a try/finally to be sure you won't leak IMAP

Comment: The code above is example code. The real one is already wrapped in a `try/finally`. But thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `UIDRetrieve()` worked as expected in revision 5022, it fails to encode the message in UTF-8 in that single-part message case.

I ended up using `UIDRetrieveText2()`, which correctly recognizes the UTF-8 encoding, though I had to fix `InternalRetrieveText()` to avoid an infinite loop.
The related code was:

```
{Get the info we want out of LParts...}
repeat
  LThePart := LParts.Items[LTextPart];   {Part 1 is index 0}
  if LThePart.FSize = 0 then begin
    {Some emails have part 0 empty, they intend you to use part 1}
    if LTextPart = 0 then begin
      LTextPart := 1;
      Continue;
    end else begin
      Break;
    end;
  end;
until False;
```

In case `LThePart.FSize` is not null, that loop would never break. So I changed it to this:

```
{Get the info we want out of LParts...}
LThePart := LParts.Items[LTextPart];   {Part 1 is index 0}
if LThePart.FSize = 0 then begin
  {Some emails have part 0 empty, they intend you to use part 1}
  LTextPart := 1;
  LThePart := LParts.Items[LTextPart];
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

`TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieve()` uses whatever charset is specified in the email itself.  If a single-part email is not decoding correctly, then it likely is not specifying a proper charset to begin with.  You will have to look at the raw email data to confirm that.  MIME encoded emails are more likely to specify charsets than plain text emails are.  Non-ASCII characters are subject to charset handling, so it is important for `TIdMessage` to know what charset an email is encoded with.

As for `UIDRetrieveText()`, it does not know the charset of the text/part part being retrieved (that is a TODO item), so it cannot decode non-ASCII characters.  `UIDRetrieveText2()`, on the other hand, fetches the email's `BODYSTRUCTURE` first and locates the `charset` of the text/part being retrieved so it can use that charset during decoding.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info about how the functions work. Note that `UIDRetrieveText2()` hangs within the `repeat` loop at line 3705 (revision 5222), because `LThePart.FSize` is `206` and so misses the break criterion. If I break the loop in case the size is not `0`, I get the correctly encoded result. Note that as shown in the question the email body has an encoding of UTF-8, so what exactly is meant by "`TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieve()` uses whatever charset is specified in the email itself"? And can I provoke `UIDRetrieve()` to encode the text in UTF-8? Or how can I decode it by myself?

Comment: I just found out that in revision 5022 I have on another PC `UIDRetrieve()` **is** returning the text correctly encoded. Also note that the message's charset is correctly recognized as UTF-8, i.e. `Msg.CharSet = 'UTF-8'` (also in revision 5223).